# Best Practices | Where to put search logic if we have different repository for each entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on an application in which have different repositories for different entities and now i have to put search logic, hence i am confused where should i put my search logic, should i create a new repository for search or should i put the logic in the existing repository, and if i should put in some existing repository the which one is it.

the repositories are listed below

```
public class VendorRepository
{

}

public class ProductRepository
{

}

Public Class ProductBatchRepository
{

}
```

Comment: Searching is a completely different beast than a simple repository. Move it into its own class and have it reference all of them.

Comment: Are all these answers just confused `Add Comment` and `Post Your Answer` buttons?

Comment: There are many possible solutions and patterns to do this, it depends on what you value with your search functionality - extensibility, speed, generics? First, respond to this: Can you return the results of your search generically? If you would put your search logic in a repository of its own - can you separate the concerns in a good way and modularize it? Does that void your semantic model in any way?

Comment: i am focusing on extensibility as it is just initial stage so my focus is not on speed for now, and I am confused because it is just a functionality and not a entity of my domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a base repository? Something like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<T>
{
    protected IDbSet<T> Query<T>()
    {
        return myContext.GetDbSet<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Query<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

   ...
}
```

and then the repositories:

```
public class ProductRepository : GenericRepository<Product>
{

}

public class VendorRepository : GenericRepository<Vendor>
{

}
```

Comment: Hey Bidoy thanks for the help and i am already following the same pattern but i am implementing free text search so for that i need to call stored procedure so thats why i wanted to put it somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach that I like to use...

...you could [seperate commands from queries](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-2/). Your commands would use the underlying domain model and repositories (as you have it now?); while your queries could use another technology; for example; query the database directly using entity framework code first.

This way you have all the flexibility of querying (using LINQ) and bypassing layers that don't add value to query purposes, and design the return types specifically for your clients. You can even use database views if that would make it easier to query.

Answer (score 1):

I would create methods for searching every entity in respective repository and create another class that would call all of them to search everything and transform the results in the desirable shape ...

Comment: I have to call a single stored procedure which will return me the list of product id and then i have to get the details from those product id

Comment: then put it in product repository ... and the code to get all the details in seperate class ...

Comment: i did implemented concept of unitOfWork and put the logic in unit of work but it again caused problem as i have to give some input object to the method which contains set of filters, hence the question is should i put the class of object in my domain project or in the BLL

Answer (score 1):

You should create search methods inside each repository this way when you want to search only products you can do ProductRepository.Search(....
This will also allow you to optimize the search method for each repository which will be quicker than one massive search.

Comment: I cant put search into every repository as it will degrade the speed of search

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but if you mean you have connections to different databases and want to implement search logic then I'd be inclined to create a class dealing specifically with search - separating this functionality from your data always tends to be good ide as it means the logic will be completely separate from any changes you might do and thereby immune from deletion if you accidentally delete the repository.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a web app you're writing, why not simply implement an anchor tag link to google? This will save you from having to write the code yourself.

Comment: its not possible because I have my own criteria to give ranking to results

Comment: Dude you didn't get me, I said i have customized logic to rank my results for example i might want to show the products first which have expiry date near by or which have discount on them and i dont think google can implement it.

Comment: @baxter - not quite: a general search engine (Google, Bing) doesn't understand your own site and data structure like you (as developer) do.

Answer (score 0):

Well Thanks to every one for taking part in the discussion, I have searched a lot about this and finally I have decided to put the logic in a different repository where as this doesn't follows best practices but this is the best solution in my problem.